# Using Lodash, how can I check to see if an object's keys match an array of strings

Tags: javascript, lodash

Let's say I have an array of strings

```
const acceptableColors = ['PURPLE', 'BLUE', 'RED', 'GREEN']
```

and I have an object

```
const primaryColors = {
  RED: 'RED',
  BLUE: 'BLUE',
  GREEN: 'GREEN',
}
```

Using Lodash, what are some of the cleanest ways I can check to see that all of the values (or keys) in the primaryColors object are present in the acceptableColors array?

Currently I think I'm close with the below function, but it still needs tweaking.

```
const containsAllColors = (primaryColors, acceptableColors) => {
   if (_.has(acceptableColors, _.every(_.values(primaryColors)))) {
   console.log('true')
   }
   console.log('false')
}
```

Comment: Great insight! You're right, this is a good way to use it outside of lodash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all keys of an object by `_.keys(object)` and all values by `_.values(object)`.

So, a cleaner (and more efficient) way in my opinion is to check if all keys are included in the `acceptableColors` and all values are also included in it.

There's a simple way to check if an array is a subset of another array with lodash:

```
_.difference(a, b).length === 0
```

I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: Brilliant! Does the job, and I learned a clean approach going forward. Thank you!

Comment: cool, happy to help. pls accept the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: also updated the first part of my answer to use lodash instead of vanilla JS.